# Printing names of local variables without values

Tags: python

I can get a dict of local variables, with the name of the variable as the key and the value as the value.

```
>>>> local_vars = locals()
>>>> len(local_vars)
34
```

if i just print `local_vars` it isn't helpful because some of the variables are too long.

I'd like to print just the variable names. But run into an interesting problem

```
>>>> for key in local_vars: print(key)
__name__
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

using dict.items() causes the same problem I believe because I still would need to create a loop.

Seems strange that `local_vars` updates when the for loop begins. Seems like it should be  static dict of the variables that exist at the time when it's set.

Comment: The `local_vars` variable is a *reference* to the original dictionary, not a copy. And the original `locals` dictionary will be updated when you enter the loop, as it introduces the new variable `key`. You need to create your own local *copy* of the `local` dictionary.

Comment: nice, coming from `R` where everything and their mother is a copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want the variable names, maybe try the folllowing:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
local_vars = dict(locals())
for variable in local_vars.keys():
    print(variable)
```

In the above code, local_vars doesn't get updated because it's a copy of the locals() dict and not a direct reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can try iterate over the copy of the "original":

```
# To get the names
for name in locals().copy().keys():
  print(name)


#To get the values:
for value in locals().copy().values():
  print(value)
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two difference locals().copy() it can affect the locals() dict.

Rather keep an assignment of locals_dct = locals() on the top so that both the loops contain the same values.

Answer (score 1):

`locals()`- Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified (`for key in locals()`)

You can use `vars()` which returns the **dict** attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a **dict** attribute when called with argument